# Rails ActionMailer error undefined email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, sendgrid

**Beginner rails error**  I'm trying to send emails out to ALL current users when an article is updated.

I have sendgrid and devise set up with my app and am able to get the mailer to work through rails console.  But, for some reason, I receive an `undefined method email for #<User::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007f8685aebec0>` when updating an article.

**ArticleNotificationMailer**

```
    class ArticleNotificationMailer < ApplicationMailer
        default from: 'you@example.com'

      def new_article(user, article)
        @user = user
        @article = article

        mail(
          to: @user.email,
          subject: "New update to article #{article.title}"
          )
      end
    end
```

**new_article.html.erb**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-type" />
      </head>
      <body>
        <h1>New article on website "<%= @article.title %>"</h1>
        <p>
          <%= @article.body %>
        </p>
        <p>
          <%= link_to "View Comment on site", article_url(@article, anchor: "updates=#{@article.id}") %>
        </p>
      </body>
    </html>
```

**ArticleController**
I'm using `ArticleNotificationMailer.new_article(@user, @article).deliver`

```
      def update
        respond_to do |format|
          if @article.update(article_params)
            ArticleNotificationMailer.new_article(@user, @article).deliver
            format.html { redirect_to @article, notice: 'Article was successfully updated.' }
            format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @article }
          else
            format.html { render :edit }
            format.json { render json: @article.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end
```

**Error Message**

```
NoMethodError in ArticlesController#update
undefined method `email' for #<User::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007f8685aebec0>

mail(
  to: @user.email,
  subject: "New post to articles #{article.title}"
  )
end
```

**Rails Console**

```
>> u = User.last
>> a = Article.first
>> ActionNotificationMailer.new_article(u, a).deliver_now
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to fix this.

I added the code below to article.rb and added @article.send_notifications! to my update controller.

```
def send_notifications!
 user = User.all
 user.each do |user|
   ArticleNotificationMailer.new_article(user, self).deliver_now
 end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 ArticleNotificationMailer.new_article(@user, @article).deliver
```

Seems like **@user** was initialized by **User.where()** in your controller. **User.where** returns an instance of **User::ActiveRecord_Relation** which is in fact rails-enhanced array. And errors comes up when you are trying to call **email** on this array.

Just use **User.find** if you need to find only one record.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing in the id of the elements.

```
class ArticleNotificationMailer < ApplicationMailer
        default from: 'you@example.com'

      def new_article(user_id, article_id)
        @user = User.where(id: user_id)
        @article = Article.where(id: article_id)

        mail(
          to: @user.email,
          subject: "New update to article #{article.title}"
          )
      end
    end


In your console 
>> u = User.last
>> a = Article.first
>> ActionNotificationMailer.new_article(u.id, a.id).deliver_now
```